# Unity WebGL: Is there a way to get a good stack trace?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am trying to track exceptions in a game I have deployed on WebGL.

I get a one-line message from this method which I am logging to a database:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceived.html

This gives me only the last line of the trace, which is not usually helpful.

I also tried a Development build with `Enable Exceptions` set to `Full Stack Trace`, but that only gave me information like this:

```
NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required.
 at MMCommon.GenericErrorDialog.Initialize (System.String message) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at MMCommon.DialogManager.OpenDialog[Object] (MMCommon.Dialog`1 dialog, System.Object arg0) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at MMCommon.Dialog`1[System.Object].Open (System.Object arg0) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  
 at MMCommon.ExceptionWatcher.LogMessageReceived (System.String condition, System.String stackTrace, LogType type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
 at UnityEngine.Application+LogCallback.Invoke
 ......
```

So that doesn't actually give me the information that I want, which is where the exception occurred in terms of file/line number, and which file/line number that came from, etc. Like the information one can get in the Unity Console.

Is it possible to get that information in a web console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be very old, but there's no way to get actual line numbers in WebGL because the actual code gets garbled by IL2CPP during the build.